# Some help understanding my own Python code

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python and I've written the following Python code (some of it omitted) and it works fine, but I'd like to understand it better. So I do the following:

```
html_doc = requests.get('[url here]')
```

Followed by:

```
if html_doc.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.text, 'html.parser')
    line = soup.find('a', class_="some_class")
    value = re.search('[regex]', str(line))
    print (value.group(0))
```

My questions are:

- What does `html_doc.text` really do? I understand that it makes "text" (a string?) out of `html_doc`, but why isn't it text already? What is it? Bytes? Maybe a stupid question but why doesn't `requests.get` create a really long string containing the HTML code?
- The only way that I could get the result of `re.search` was by `value.group(0)` but I have literally no idea what this does. Why can't I just look at `value` directly? I'm passing it a string, there's only one match, why is the resulting `value` not a string?

Comment: Using `re` module and its search method you don't get as a return value just a string, but Match object. You want to get 0 (first) group from this object, but you could easily get another one, if it's there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requests.get()` return value, as stated in docs, is [Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object.

`re.search()` return value, as stated in docs, is [MatchObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) object.

Both objects are introduced, because they contain much more information than simply response bytes (e.g. HTTP status code, response headers etc.) or simple found string value (e.g. it includes positions of first and last matched characters).

For more information you'll have to study docs.

FYI, to check type of returned value you may use built-in `type` function:

```
response = requests.get('[url here]')
print type(response)  #  <class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you are lacking some basic knowledge about Classes, Object and methods...etc, you need to read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) (for Python 2.7) and about requests module [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/).

Concerning what you asked, when you type `html_doc = requests.get('url')`, you are creating an instance of class `requests.models.Response`, you can check it by:

```
>>> type(html_doc)
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Now, `html_doc` has methods, thus `html_doc.text` will return to you the server's response

Same goes for `re` module, each of its methods generates response object that are not simply `int` or `string`